# Interpreting coefficients in AFT model

Tags: interpretation, exponential-distribution

I'm using an AFT (accelerated failure time) model with an exponential distribution to study the speed of adopting a new innovation. One of my independent variables is cumulative adoption, which is negative and highly significant. What's the best way to interpret this? Does it mean that as more and more actors adopt the innovation, the speed of adoption also gets faster? Thanks!